# Visual Studio Error "Unable to start program: The system cannot find the specified file."

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, fopen

I'm working on a project and have been unable to have Visual Studio 2019 access any input/output files at all.  I have resorted to using sample code and templates found online but still have not found any luck and continue to get the error of "Unable to start program, The system cannot find the specified file."

I have created a new project using the Window Desktop Wizard and creating a source file of "main.c" as my professor has instructed us to do for other C programming assignments.  I have tried Build > Build Solution as well as change the .txt to a "Yes" for Content (under properties) as some guides have suggested but none of the above seem to fix the problem!  Here is the sample code (not my own) that I have been attempting to use for reference! Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /* Pointer to the file */
    FILE* fp1;
    /* Character variable to read the content of file */
    char c;

    /* Opening a file in r mode*/
    fp1 = fopen("newfile.txt", "r" );

    /* Infinite loop –I have used break to come out of the loop*/
    while (1)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp1);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        else
            printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to be sure that "newfile.txt" is in the same folder that your program is running from.  When VS builds a project, the executable will normally be in a "Debug" or "Release" folder.

Comment: Unable to start program, The system cannot find the specified file.", This is not related to the txt file but with the source file, try right clicking on Source Files in Your Project --> Add --> New Item 
then the source file.

Comment: *sample code (not my own) * isn't useful. If you want us to help you figure out why your code isn't working, post YOUR code.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have "newfile.txt"  in the same directory as that of the source code file..
Alternative solution is change the read mode to write mode so that the compiler will create a file (if not exists) 
The code should  should be like this-

fp1 = fopen("newfile.txt", "w" );

Comment: I double checked it was in the same directory (it was) and still the same error. I then used your suggestion to change it to write and the error is still appearing.

Comment: You don't get a *cannot start program* error for the text file being in the wrong location. You get the error because the program **cannot be started** in the first place, which means that the code never runs.